What is name of := symbol？
I have never heard anyone refer to the ':=' symbol by its name. However, I am curious to know if it does indeed have a specific name.

It usually means "is defined as", so people just call it that. Someone might also call it "colon equal" because of the LaTeX command \coloneqq.

I am not positive but I believe it is "is defined to be..". As in '$x:=y$' is '$x$ is defined to be $y$'. But in general it is good to use both words and symbols whenever there is doubt, say. "We present another variable $x$ and define it in terms of $y$, specifically $x :=2y$"...

The Python name for it is the "walrus operator"

What's the difference between := and plain $=$?

@Hudjefa "is defined as" and "is equal to"

@BoweiTang, gracias. Can you show me example sentences where I can tell the difference between the two. Mike above gave this example, $x := 2y$, but isn't that the same as $x = 2y$?

@Hudjefa In the first case, $x$ is defined to be $2y$, you cannot switch these two(i.e $2y:=x$) since $2y$ is already well-defined; but for the second case, $x=2y$ is the same as $2y=x$.

@BoweiTang, will look into it. Muchas gracias.

Which is correct? 1) $\cosh x := \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$ or 2) $\cosh x = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$? @BoweiTang

@Hudjefa If you want to tell others what is $\cosh x$, then it is better to use one as for 2, it may be confusing whether it is a definition or something derived from other equations. But if you write it in the exam, we always use 2 because we are not defining it, we just use this fact. But notice that it is not good to write $\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}=\cosh x$(i.e. do not switch their positions) as it looks like defining the left using $\cosh x$ even if using "=".
